# datables issue using PDO, CSS and JQUERY

Tags: jquery, css, pdo

i have a page that has datatables with database on it, the datatable itself is working fine but my problem is that when i reload/refresh my page all the records in that datatables are all showing it should not show all the records because in my datatable has a pagination, but everytime i reload/refresh my page it always showing all the records and when the reload/refreshing is finish the datatable is come to normal state again. my issue is when reloading/refreshing the page..

**here is my code**
**index.php**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="datatable/media/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="datatable/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="datatable/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

**script.js**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.table-bordered').dataTable({
        "scrollY":        "300px", //Scroll vertical
        "scrollX":        "true", //Scroll Horizontal
        "iDisplayLength": 20, //Display 20 records Per Page
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":         true //Pagination

        });
    });
```

**css**

```
 .table_wrapper{
    margin-top:5px;
    max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:60px;
    overflow:auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 30px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 30px -6px black;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 30px -6px black;
    height:auto;
 }
 .table-bordered{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-size: 13px;
 }
 thead th{
    background-color:#6a782a;
    color:#FFF;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
 }
 tbody td{
    word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

**and here is my code for the body/table**

```
 <div class="table_wrapper">
    <table class="table table-bordered" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>LO Name</th>
            <th>Province</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Title Number</th>
            <th>Lot Number</th>
            <th>Survey Number</th>
            <th>Module Number</th>
            <th>Land Type</th>
            <th>Area</th>
            <th>Remarks</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM survey_section";
                    $crud->dataview($query);

                 ?>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$query = "SELECT * FROM survey_section";` is not the way to do pagination.

One way using PDO is

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `survey_section` LIMIT ?, ?";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(1,$offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(2,$rowsperpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Where $offset is page number, from $POST[] or GET[] and $rowsperpage for lenghth of page ,20 in your case.

Comment: iw ill try your code..it will be able to fix my problem?